# Laravel 6 Validator to setLocale() when field is presented

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have API, so when front sends to me "language" I want Validator to setLocale() and show an error(from resources/lang/ru/validation.php) message in requested language.

Now I have this code, which works:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'supplier_id' => 'required|integer',
            'language' => 'required',
        ]);
        App::setLocale($request->language);
        if ($validator->fails()).....
```

I want to remove App::setLocale, add custom rule "lang" and change it to:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'supplier_id' => 'required|integer',
            'language' => 'required|lang',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails())....
```

So from here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#using-extensions in Providers/AppServiceProvider.php I added this:

```
public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('lang', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            //die(var_dump([$attribute/*"language"*/, $value/*"ru"*/, $parameters/*[]*/]));
            App::setLocale($value);return $value;
        });
    }
```

What I've missed? Maybe there is another solution?

Comment: I've tested your code, and for me it works. Maybe your routes are cached? Try `php artisan route:clear` maybe even `php artisan cache:clear`?

Comment: @RobBiermann I use composer dump-autoload & php artisan config:clear & php artisan config:cache & php artisan cache:clear & php artisan route:clear   -and it is not working

Comment: @RobBiermann Have just tried this on fresh new installation v6 and not worked with all php artisan clean and clear commands. Maybe your installation has something special?)

Comment: I'm running on laravel 7.1.3. How are you currently concluding it does not work? Are the messages not translated? Can you try `dd(App::getLocale());` somewhere after the validation? Note that in this case I would expect to get `ru` back, as long as you provide it in the request.

Comment: @RobBiermann So I've installed v7.6 and after validation added if ($validator->fails()){ return response()->json(['getLocale' => App::getLocale(), 'errors'=>$validator->errors()]); }    And again not works. Here is what I get:  {"getLocale":"ru","errors":{"supplier_id":["The supplier id field is required."]}}   Anyway, thanks for your time!

Comment: Sorry, i thought it did not set it to `ru`, but what I understand now, is it does not translate, EVEN if set to `ru`. My bad, what happens when you change the rules around? So first validation = lang and then rest